# Flutter & Dart Error Handling Middleware Concept

Tags: flutter, dart

I check my errors between try blocks. How can I get rid of code repetition by creating an intermediate layer instead of rewriting it within each method?

As seen in the codes, I use try blocks in all operations.

```
Future<List<Post>> getAll(){
  try {
    //http get code
  }on SocketException {
    throw Failure('Message');
  }on HttpException {
    throw Failure("Http Exception Message");
  }on FormatException {
    throw Failure("Format Message");
  }
}

Future<Post> getPost(){
  try {
    //http get code
  }on SocketException {
    throw Failure('Message');
  }on HttpException {
    throw Failure("Http Exception Message");
  }on FormatException {
    throw Failure("Format Message");
  }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of one of your method and pass in the URL string and action whether that be GET, POST, PUT, etc. as parameters.